# What to do if the titanium restful API call fails?

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js, titanium-mobile

Currently I display an alert informing the user that the API call has failed. However there are situations where I need the API call to be successful, otherwise data integrity is affected.

```
//key press changed

    $.txtNick.addEventListener('return', function(e) {

        //create a collection
        var usersCollection = Alloy.Collections.user;

        var tempJSON = {};
        usersCollection.fetch({

            success : function() {

                var getModel = usersCollection.where(checkFBAccountIdJSON);

                for (var i in getModel) {

                    //update local model
                    getModel[i].set('nickname', $.txtNick.value);
                    //save changes
                    getModel[i].save();

                }

                console.log(usersCollection.toJSON());

                tempJSON = usersCollection.toJSON();
                //post to API

                if (Titanium.Network.online) {

                    //console.log(tempJSON);

                    apiHelper.APIPostRequest(Alloy.GlobalsAPI + '/user', tempJSON, function(e) {
                        var status = this.status;
                        if (status == 200) {

                            console.log('nickname posted');


                        }
                    }, function(err) {

                        alert('Unknown error from api');
                    });

                } else {
                    alert('No internet connection found');
                }

            },
            error : function() {
                // something is wrong..
            }
        });
        //end

    });
```

In this case, if someone changes their nickname, first the local model is updated, then the updated object from the model is sent to a server. The problem I may have here in future, is if the API call to the server is not successfully made, meaning that the nickname stored in the server is out of date with the one stored in the model.

What is the best way to deal with these type of situations? Thanks

Comment: Can you not just update the model at client and not actually save on server? It will give user feeling of updation. then perform API call. If it is success, then update nickname on server. hope this will help

Comment: That's how I am doing it currently, but the trouble is eventually I need to perform API calls to the server.

Comment: But I do not see any problem in that. There are many more chances in any application that asynchronous call fails. You just have to be honest with user and display appropriate message informing user that there is a problem in updation with most possible reasons.

Comment: It can be problomatic in the sense that if the user logs out, and then relogs in again, the way I have coded it is so that the models are updated with the data fetched from the remote server, hence why data integrity is key. Also if this happens too often, chances are, we would have stored out of date data in our remote server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a local update (model) and a remote update (API). Chances are that you will always be able to locally update, and not always do it remotely, so, my suggestion is: try to update thru your API call and if it is successfull you update locally. If API update fail, don't update it locally.

This way you bind both operations atomically (sort of).

Comment: Yeah, as I thought - is this the right way to do it in your opinion?